# REST API - CreatedAtRoute method doesn't return a value

Tags: rest, http-post, entity-framework-core, postman

I'm building some REST API server in .NET Core and using Postman software to test it. I have a problem with POST method which doesn't return me any value ("Could not get any response") when I try to perform second Add operation on my DBContext class inside `CreateUser` method. My code :

UsersController :

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly DBContext _context;

    #region CONSTRUCTOR

    public UsersController(DBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    #endregion

    #region HTTP GET

    // GET: api/users || api/users?cardnr=xxx
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers(string cardNr)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cardNr))
        {
            try
            {
                var users = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();

                if (users.Any())
                {
                    return Json(users);
                }
                else
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Cards.Any(c => c.CardNumber.Equals(cardNr)));

                if (user == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ObjectResult(user);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }
    }

    //GET: api/users/1
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetUserByID")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserByID(Int32 id)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.IDUser == id);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                return new ObjectResult(user);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region HTTP POST

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser([FromBody] Models.User userToCreate, string userGroupID)
    {
        if (userToCreate == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Users.Add(userToCreate);

                int parsingResult;

                // if user passed userGroupID
                if (userGroupID != null)
                {
                    // parsing if userGroupID is a number
                    if (!int.TryParse(userGroupID, out parsingResult))
                    {
                        return BadRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // if client want to assign a new user to some group
                        if (parsingResult > 0)
                        {
                            // creating new record in UserGroup table - assigning a user to group
                            var userGroup = new Models.UserGroup();
                            _context.Entry(userGroup).Property("IDGroup").CurrentValue = parsingResult;
                            _context.Entry(userGroup).Property("IDUser").CurrentValue = userToCreate.IDUser;

                            _context.UserGroups.Add(userGroup); // NOTE HERE
                        }
                    }
                }

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return CreatedAtRoute("GetUserByID", new { id = userToCreate.IDUser }, userToCreate);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

User model :

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int IDUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<UserGroup> UsersGroups { get; set; }
}
```

UserGroup model :

```
public class UserGroup
{
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext class :

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DBContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // shadow property - foreign key
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>()
            .Property<int>("IDUser");

        // shadow property - foreign key
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>()
            .Property<int>("IDGroup");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>()
            .HasKey( new string[]{ "IDUser", "IDGroup" });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>()
            .HasOne(ug => ug.Group)
            .WithMany(g => g.UsersGroups)
            .HasForeignKey("IDGroup");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>()
            .HasOne(ug => ug.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.UsersGroups)
            .HasForeignKey("IDUser");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

The problem lies in `HttpPost` method in `UsersController`.
When I do "normal" POST and pass JSON object which contain a user to add without assigning it to group (empty userGroupID parameter) everything is ok - user gets added to the DataBase and Postman returns me a user with its ID.

screen :
[image: https://pasteboard.co/GFUgMeM.png]

and when I try to add a new user but with adding it to specific group I always get an error :

screen :
[image]

Even despite that error new user gets properly added to DB and associated with its group (record gets added to UserGroup table; UserGroup is join table between Users and Groups table). So I have proper data in my DB but I always get this error and I can't return new added user to client who called API and can't get his ID. Am I doing something wrong in my `CreateUser` method ?

**UPDATE** :

I have added a comment line in "NOTE HERE" in `CreateUser` method in `UsersController`. If I comment whole this line I don't get an error from Postman but obviously I don't get my User associated with its group (I don't get new record added to UserGroup join table). So it seems like another `Add` method on context object causing an error ... Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug it?

Set a breakpoint on the row:

```
if (userToCreate == null)
```

Send again the request with Postman and debug your app. There you can see what and where it goes wrong.

Please let me know how it is going so I know how can I help you:)

Comment: Hi Andrei. Thanks for your answer. Yes I have tried debuging my app and `if (userToCreate == null)` always returns false which means user is correctly passed to `CreateUser` method. Moreover it's correctly added to DB and it's correctly assigned to a group (UserGroup table saves correct new record). I still have this Postman error